# IntelliJ scala console, interactive developement

Tags: scala, intellij-idea

I have just started "coding" in Scala, coming from F# I am trying to find a way to have a similar environement.

Currently I am using IntelliJ 10.0.2. with the Scala plugin. On any  given project I am trying to set up the following:

- When opened the scala console loads the external libraries of the project ( this works )
- A command/way to load the files where code is under developement. For instance you define a few modules in your project that you would like to test, so you would do something like load "module1.scala", load"module2.scala" etc.. in the console.

Is this possible?

Note:

- com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.org.jetbrains.plugins.scala.compiler.rt.ConsoleRunner seems to load all the external libraries
- *there seems to be a function :load but when I supply it arguments it returns "file does not exist")* actually was just a silly mistake was using C: instead of c:

Many thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Google for the sbt plugin for idea. SBT (Simple Build Tool) is an interactive build tool for Scala. It has a "console" command that loads the dependencies and your classes when it starts up. SBT offers other goodies, as well. The idea plugin lets you use the two together.

Answer (score 2):

It's not possible like IntelliJ IDEA feature.
You can add appropriate issue to Scala plugin issue tracker: http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issues/SCL.